# Preserving indentation in a triple-quoted fstring

Tags: python, python-3.x, indentation, f-string

I am trying to use a triple-quoted strings in Python3(.7) to build some formated strings.

I have a list of inner strings, which all need to be tabbed in:

```
    This is some text
    across multiple
    lines.
```

And a string which should contain the inner string

```
data{
    // string goes here
}
```

I cannot tab the inner string when I create it. So, my thought was to use `dedent` with Python3 triple-quoted fstrings:

```
import textwrap

inner_str = textwrap.dedent(
    '''\
    This is some text
    across multiple
    lines.'''
)

full_str = textwrap.dedent(
    f'''\
    data{{
        // This should all be tabbed
        {inner_str}
    }}'''
)

print(full_str)
```

However, the indentation is not maintained:

```
    data{
        // This should all be tabbed
        This is some text
across multiple
lines.
    }
```

The desired result:

```
data{
    // This should all be tabbed
    This is some text
    across multiple
    lines.
}
```

How can I preserve the indentation of the fstring without pre-tabbing the inner string?

Comment: Have you tried using `\n` and `\t` as formatting options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the answers here seemed to do what I want, so I'm answering my own question with a solution which gets as close to what I was looking for as I can make. It is not required to pre-tab the data to define its indentation level, nor is it required to not indent the line (which breaks readability). Instead, the indentation level of the current line *in the fstring* is passed at usage time.

Not perfect but it works.

```
import textwrap


def code_indent(text, tab_sz, tab_chr=' '):
    def indented_lines():
        for i, line in enumerate(text.splitlines(True)):
            yield (
                tab_chr * tab_sz + line if line.strip() else line
            ) if i else line
    return ''.join(indented_lines())


inner_str = textwrap.dedent(
    '''\
    This is some text
    across multiple
    lines.'''
)


full_str = textwrap.dedent(
    f'''
    data{{
        {code_indent(inner_str, 8)}
    }}'''
)

print(full_str)
```

Answer (score 4):

This seems to provide what you want.

```
import textwrap

inner_str = textwrap.dedent(
    '''\
    This is some text
    across multiple
    lines.'''
)

full_str = textwrap.dedent(
    f'''
    data{{
{textwrap.indent(inner_str, "        ")}
    }}'''
)
```

A better solution:

```
idt = str.maketrans({'\n': "\n        "})
print(textwrap.dedent(
    f'''
    data{{
        {inner_str.translate(idt)}
    }}'''
))
```

Another solution with customized tab width:

```
def indent_inner(inner_str, indent):
    return inner_str.replace('\n', '\n' + indent)   # os.linesep could be used if the function is needed across different OSs

print(textwrap.dedent(
    f'''
    data{{
        {indent_inner(inner_str, "        ")}
    }}'''
))
```

Comment: This is good except that the inner line code cannot be tabbed during the f-string, which ruins the readability issue originally solved with dedent.

Comment: I've updated the answer with another solution. If it fulfills your need you could consider to upvote and accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Edited to avoid tabbing `inner_str`.

```py
import textwrap

line_tab = '\n\t'

inner_str = f'''\
This is some text
across multiple
lines.
'''

full_str = textwrap.dedent(f'''\
data{{
    // This should all be tabbed 
    {line_tab.join(inner_str.splitlines())}
}}''')
                           )

print(full_str)
```

Output:

```
data{
    // This should all be tabbed 
    This is some text
    across multiple
    lines.
}
```

Comment: I do not want to tab the original string, and using the `\t` construction everywhere will quickly ruin readability. That's why I was using `dedent`

Comment: Edited to use `join()` and `splitlines()`